# Enabling and forcing customers to fill their information

Tags: woocommerce

With WooCommerce, I want to Enabling and forcing customers to fill their information when Registered
for example when you registered in my shop, show a menu that say "fill your information"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the validation of your fields using the actions and filters mechanism provided already by woocommerce, for more information see [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

```
     // Hook in
     add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

     // Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
     function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
          $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = true;

          return $address_fields;
    }
```